# postgresql query performance enhancement

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sql-execution-plan

**I am trying to get a row with highest popularity. Ordering by descending popularity is slowing down the query significantly. 
Is there a better way to optimize this query ?**

Postgresql - 9.5

````
    ```explain analyse SELECT  v.cosmo_id,
            v.resource_id, k.gid, k.popularity,v.cropinfo_id
            FROM rmsg.verifications V INNER JOIN rmip.resourceinfo R ON
            (R.id=V.resource_id AND R.source_id=54) INNER JOIN rmpp.kgidinfo K ON 
            (K.cosmo_id=V.cosmo_id) WHERE V.status=1 AND 
            v.crop_Status=1 AND V.locked_time isnull ORDER BY k.popularity 
            desc, (v.cosmo_id,
            v.resource_id, v.cropinfo_id) LIMIT 1;```


        QUERY PLAN                                                                                

        Limit  (cost=470399.99..470399.99 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=19655.552..19655.553 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort  (cost=470399.99..470434.80 rows=13923 width=31) (actual time=19655.549..19655.549 rows=1 loops=1)
            Sort Key: k.popularity DESC, (ROW(v.cosmo_id, v.resource_id, v.cropinfo_id))
            Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=19053.91..470330.37 rows=13923 width=31) (actual time=58.365..19627.405 rows=23006 loops=1)
                   ->  Hash Join  (cost=19053.48..459008.74 rows=13188 width=16) (actual time=58.275..19268.339 rows=19165 loops=1)
                         Hash Cond: (v.resource_id = r.id)
                         ->  Seq Scan on verifications v  (cost=0.00..409876.92 rows=7985725 width=16) (actual time=0.035..11097.163 rows=9908140 loops=1)
                               Filter: ((locked_time IS NULL) AND (status = 1) AND (crop_status = 1))
                               Rows Removed by Filter: 1126121
                         ->  Hash  (cost=18984.23..18984.23 rows=5540 width=4) (actual time=57.101..57.101 rows=5186 loops=1)
                               Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 247kB
                               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on resourceinfo r  (cost=175.37..18984.23 rows=5540 width=4) (actual time=2.827..51.318 rows=5186 loops=1)
                                     Recheck Cond: (source_id = 54)
                                     Heap Blocks: exact=5907
                                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resourceinfo_source_id_key  (cost=0.00..173.98 rows=5540 width=0) (actual time=1.742..1.742 rows=6483 loops=1)
                                           Index Cond: (source_id = 54)
        Index Scan using kgidinfo_cosmo_id_idx on kgidinfo k  (cost=0.43..0.85 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=1 loops=19165)
                         Index Cond: (cosmo_id = v.cosmo_id)
     Planning time: 1.083 ms
     Execution time: 19655.638 ms
    (21 rows)```
````

Comment: Please try: http://tatiyants.com/postgres-query-plan-visualization/

Comment: Start by removing the extra parentheses, especially at: `(v.cosmo_id,
            v.resource_id, v.cropinfo_id)` Plus: add {table structure, indexes, cardinality, tuning} to your question

Comment: @wildplasser I have removed the parenthesis, the execution time has improved slightly, I'll try adding indexes and see if the execution time improves

Comment: Try adding this index: create index on rmsg.verifications (resource_id, cosmo_id) where locked_time is null and status=1 and crop_status=1; Then analyze that table and try again. Try reversing the resource_id and cosmo_id too to see if one is faster than the other.

Comment: Note that a dandy resource for looking at explain plans exists here:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/L2em

Comment: @ScottMarlowe Okay, I'll add out these indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query, simplified by removing parentheses:

```
SELECT v.cosmo_id, v.resource_id, k.gid, k.popularity, v.cropinfo_id
FROM rmsg.verifications V INNER JOIN
     rmip.resourceinfo R
     ON R.id = V.resource_id AND R.source_id = 54 INNER JOIN
     rmpp.kgidinfo K
     ON K.cosmo_id = V.cosmo_id
WHERE V.status = 1 AND v.crop_Status = 1 AND
      V.locked_time is null
ORDER BY k.popularity desc, v.cosmo_id, v.resource_id, v.cropinfo_id
LIMIT 1;
```

For this query, I would think in terms of indexes on `verifications(status, crop_status, locked_time, resource_id, cosmo_id, crop_info_id)`, `resourceinfo(id, source_id)`, and `kgidinfo(cosmo_id)`.  I don't see an easy way to remove the `ORDER BY`.

In looking at the query, I wonder if you might have a Cartesian product problem between the two tables.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the headsup ! 
I'll look if this might end up having a cartesian product problem.

Comment: The number of rows you get from joins doesn't suggest a cartesian product. Your biggest time killer is the seq scan of the v. table, and the second one is the join of the rather large number of rows that match.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe Is there a way to avoid the seq scan of verifications table

Comment: Hopefully that index I suggested will do the trick. If not, you might be able to get individual queries on each column to combine in a bitmap hash